# How can I parse such xml having one tags and different arguments in it?

Tags: iphone, nsxmlparser

How can I parse such xml, having one node and different arguments in it using NSXMLParser?

```
 <vendorlist>

 <statusdescription>success</statusdescription>

 <statuscode>200</statuscode>

 <statistic vendor_count="1" page="1" page_count="1"/>

  <vendor id="1581" name="Islan Name is here" street="The address is here" state="USVI" zip="802" phone1="340-774-3944" phone2="" email="example@abcd.org" website1="" website2="" longitude="" latitude="" description="this is very important discription here, for this vendor" picture_img="http://igy.match3win.com/img/picture/NULL" logo_img="http://igy.match3win.com/img/logo/1581.jpg"/>


  </vendorlist>
```

Here Vendor has different parameters in it, so how can parse it using nsxmlparser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using NSXMLParser, your delegate will implement the method [`parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSXMLParserDelegate). When it's called with element name of "vendor", `attributes` will be a `NSDictionary` with the "parameters". Looking for missing parameters in the dictionary will return `nil`.

The official documentation has a [XML Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/XMLParsing.html) with lots of example code, including on how to [handle elements and attributes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/Articles/HandlingElements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002265-BCIJFGJI).

Comment: @Veer Sure, let me get my rate sheet.

Comment: first code, only for above line, I will upvote and accept answer,

Comment: I got the idea, yet confused about disctionary,

Comment: @Veer If you're confused about using NSDictionary, post a separate question about that. I also added links to the relevant guide in the official documentation, it contains example code as well.

Comment: "how about no", what no, number

Comment: @Veer If you need further clarification for this question, then yes, post a comment. If you need to ask something unrelated, post a new question. You may not have my contact information unless you're actually willing to pay me for my time.

Comment: May be I will offer you some sort of contract base job, think, thanks for help, cya

Comment: @Veer Whoops, seems I lost the edit with the links I mentioned. I added them now, you can find example code there.